# How to query MultiIndex with nested levels?

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to use `query` with a MultiIndex that has multiple levels of columns.

```
!pip install pandas-datareader --quiet
```

Next ...

```
from pandas_datareader import DataReader

df = DataReader(["SPY", "XOM"],  "yahoo", datetime(2012,7,1), datetime(2018,7,21))
df.keys()
```

Returns ...

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close'], ['SPY', 'XOM']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=['Attributes', 'Symbols'])
```

And

```
df['High']['SPY'].head()
```

Returns ...

```
Date
2012-07-02    136.649994
2012-07-03    137.509995
2012-07-05    137.800003
2012-07-06    135.770004
2012-07-09    135.570007
Name: SPY, dtype: float64
```

I was wondering how to use `query` with multiple levels?  I was thinking something like this?

```
df.query('High.SPY > 137')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIU this is only partially supported - see [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13348) on GH.

That post suggests using this syntax:

```
df.query('@df.High.SPY > 137')
```

If you don't have a specific need to use `query`, it's doable with `loc`:

```
df.loc[:, ('High', 'SPY')][df.loc[:, ('High', 'SPY')] > 137]
```

Or alternatively:

```
df[df.loc[:, ('High', 'SPY')] > 137].loc[:,('High', 'SPY')]


Date
2012-07-03    137.509995
2012-07-05    137.800003
2012-07-18    137.639999
2012-07-19    138.179993
2012-07-20    137.160004
2012-07-27    139.070007
2012-07-30    139.339996
2012-07-31    138.869995
...
```

Comment: Edited - now I think it's OK

Comment: also `df.loc[:, ('High', 'SPY')] ` - `df[('High', 'SPY')] `

Comment: where is the `> 137`?

Comment: I think simplify `df.loc[:, ('High', 'SPY')]` , `> 137` is also necessary :)